# Recorrer DataSet y formar un nuevo DataSet a partir de información del primero

Tags: vb.net, .net, foreach, dataset

Tengo un Dataset `ds` que contiene varios registros en una sola tabla, la cual sigue una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
    DNI   |    NOMBRE    |    TIPO_MOV    |    MONTO    
---------------------------------------------------
    18        Dia             Azul            11213
    18        Dia             Rojo            656
    18        Dia             Azul            11888
    18        Dia             Azul            5677
    20        Noche           Rojo            4566
    20        Noche           Rojo            6695
    20        Noche           Azul            4856
```

Sin embargo, necesito crear otro dataset `ds2` que siga la misma estructura, pero que sólo contenga los movimientos de un sólo `DNI`, dado que debo volcar la información en un informe, el informe contiene la información asociada a sólo un `DNI`. Luego este nuevo DataSet `ds2` se limpiará con la instrucción `Clear()` para que el ciclo vuelva a llenarlo con cada uno de los `DNI` restantes que queden en el DataSet `ds` inicial.

Sin embargo, al parecer algo estoy haciendo mal, dado que sólo he podido dar con el recorrido del dataset por filas, pero no he podido discriminar automáticamente y de forma que se pueda grabar la información de un sólo `DNI` al nuevo DataSet:

```
Dim dsTotal   as new DataSet
Dim dsCliente as new DataSet

For Each DniCli as DataRow in ds.Tables(0).Rows
    ' Grabado informacion específica a nuevo DataSet
    ' Generación informe
    ' procesamiento de más información asociada
    ' ds2.Clear()
Next
```

Entonces mi pregunta es, dado que necesito diferenciar información por sólo un campo, cómo podría implementarlo? Intenté con la instrucción `Select()` , pero está muy limitada a mi juicio. Estoy trabajando con `Visual Studio 2012`

Saludos y muchas gracias de antemano